# Rebuilding a Newer Version of a Deb Package

Tags: ubuntu, versioning, debian, rebuild, package-management

What's the best way to update (rebuild) a Debian/Ubuntu-package to a more recent version? Should I be using `apt source` in all cases including when I want to publish it as Personal Package Archive? I would like to have Intel TBB 4.0 instead of 3.0, which is pre-packaged in Ubuntu 11.10.

Answer (score 3):

You should follow the standard procedure of the [Debian New Maintainer's Guide](http://www.debian.org/doc/manuals/maint-guide/) ([Section 8.3](http://www.debian.org/doc/manuals/maint-guide/update.en.html#newupstream)) even when deploying to a Personal Package Archive. That is, get the current debian packaging control using `apt-get source`, unpack the TBB 4.0 source, unpack the Debian .tar.gz, do the "chores" described in Section 8.3. (New upstream release) and then build the package to obtain the new .deb.

The reason for following this procedure is simply tool support: All Debian tools are intended for this standard use, and they provide excellent support and automation when used properly. You can cut some corners when you have understood this system.